# How do I write the result a 'get' in nodejs to a file?

Tags: node.js

I've got a code that prints on my screen the result of a get. The excerpt of the code that does this is the following:

```
http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));

  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    process.stdout.write(chunk);
  });
}).on('error', function (e) {
  console.log('ERROR: ' + e.message);
});
```

I want it to write the results to a file instead. How can I do it? In which folder should I save the file, in order to avoid any possible windows security blocks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use nodes file system

```
var fs = require('fs');

http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));

  res.on('data', function(chunk) {
    fs.writeFile('message.txt', chunk, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('It\'s saved!');
    });
  });
}).on('error', function (e) {
  console.log('ERROR: ' + e.message);
});
```